# How to pass a variable from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

If I pass an hard coded numeric value from php to javascript, all works perfectly. But if i pass the numeric value from a variable, i get an error:

javascript file (gallery.js)

```
function goto_anchor(id)
{
    var anchor = $("#anchor_" + id);

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: anchor.offset().top - 20
    }, 1200);
}
```

php file

```
....
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/gallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script><?php

$get_cat = 4;

if (isset($get_cat)) { ?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            goto_anchor(4); // this will work PERFECTLY!!!
            goto_anchor(<?php echo $get_cat; ?>); // this will NOT work !!!
        });
    </script><?php
} ?>
```

I need to pass the $get_cat variable in my php, not the harcoded numeric value. How ??
Thanks

Comment: What is being rendered when you run that? That should work.

Comment: i doesnt scroll to the anchor and i get the javascript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: Right click and view source, what is actually written to the page?

Comment: no, the hard coded 4 works!

Comment: Look at what your PHP is actually outputting. That should be your first step in diagnosing problems like this, and it's going to give you an obvious cause in almost every case. As it stands, we can't possibly help. If your first line, `goto_anchor(4)` works PERFECLTY!!!, then your second line must necessarily work. You've either omitted details, or misinterpreted your error.

Comment: David: on the source i clearly see the correct numeric value beeing send. But why the error?

Comment: @Marco, if after the PHP is run, you see `goto_anchor(4);` where the source has `goto_anchor(<?php echo $get_cat; ?>);` then you have a JS error, not a PHP. Because once it's run through the PHP preprocessor, it might as well have been hardcoded.

Comment: David: exactly, the error is from jquery: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: im going crazy trying to figure it out. where do i post the test case?

Comment: finally, found what the error was. It has to do with anonymous function.. fix it and it works

Answer (score 0):

I have such kind of problems before, can not fill

```
javascriptfunction(<?php echo $phpvirable ?>)
```

inside javascript function that causes error; Instead , according to your code, can echo it to javascript virable first before using it;

```
echo '<script> var get_cat = '.$get_cat.'</script>';
```

into your php

```
<?php   $get_cat = 4;  ?>
```

surely, Your php $get_cat can be captured from such as $_REQUEST['cat'] dynamic value from form submit event towards this page. then u convert it to javascript virable to use in function.

```
<?php
if(isset($getcat)):
echo '<script> var get_cat = '.$getcat.'</script>';
endif;
?> 
// javascript function read predefined javascript virable that confirm work.

// u also avoid using mixed php and javascript statements which looks messy
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
         goto_anchor(get_cat); // this will work then.
    });
</script>
```